# Need more information on this situation

Tags: android, runtime-error, toast

Some of my coding is as follows. The first button (button2) is for exit which is working fine on my emulator and phone but the (button 1) which is supposed to take input from a TextView and add 777 and then display as a toast message is not working in either of them.

```
public class TimerCodeActivity extends Activity {

protected TextView timebox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timerlayout);

    timebox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timebox);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);}
    });    

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){    

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            String timeboxRepresentation = (String) timebox.getText();

             int Digit = Integer.parseInt(timeboxRepresentation.substring(0,2));
             int total = Digit + 777;

             Toast.makeText(TimerCodeActivity.this, String.valueOf(total), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: not working in what way, what is it displaying? and please think of a better title

Comment: what question and what error here?what the timeboxRepresentation contain?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your problem, but you should never call `System.exit(0)` in an Android app. Just call `finish()`, it will do the job properly.

Comment: "is not working" is fine but what is the exception? update your question with logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class TimerCodeActivity extends Activity {

protected TextView timebox;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timerlayout);

    timebox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timebox);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });    

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){    

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Use toString to get the TextView content  
            String timeboxRepresentation = timebox.getText().toString();

             int Digit = Integer.parseInt(timeboxRepresentation.substring(0,2));
             int total = Digit + 777;

             Toast.makeText(TimerCodeActivity.this, String.valueOf(total), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

and just remove

```
System.exit(0);
```

it's useless.

Comment: where must i put the first line ou told me?